# Is it possible to set the filePath and fileName of sails-disk adapter on a per-model basis?

Tags: sails.js

I'm aware that I can change where the localDisk.db ends up by changing the config/connections.js

```
localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk',
    filePath: '/data/',
    fileName: 'myName.db'
}
```

But is it possible to set this up on a per-model basis?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found my own answer by carefully looking at the documentation.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings

I can set the connection on a per-model basis, which means I could have a User.db, Host.db, etc. all defined as different settings in the config/connections.js:

```
localHostsDB: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk',
    filePath: '/data/',
    fileName: 'hosts.db'
},
localUsersDB: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk',
    filePath: '/data/',
    fileName: 'users.db'
},
```

and then at the top of my api/models/Host.js:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'localHostsDb',
  attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string', required: true, unique: true },
```